# How to parse a float, sent by a Bluetooth device, in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point, portability

On my iOS app I need to decode a Float value received by bluetooth and taking 4 bytes from a different device ( not iOS) so I need a "portable" 4-byte Float format . For now the sender is using this format:

Data codification: 0xCCBBAAEE
-   0xEE:       Exponent, 1 signed byte.
-   0xCCBBAA:   Mantissa, 3 signed bytes.

My question is: how can I construct an (ios) Float from such Exponent and the Mantissa?

in iOS Float has this initializer:
public init(sign: FloatingPointSign, exponent: Int, significand: Float)

I can easily work out the sign param from the signed Mantissa, the Exp param from the signed Exponent but the significant parameter takes a Float BUT the significand param is a Float and I only receive a 3-bytes mantissa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are following the [standard IEEE format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32), which really looks you are — I have a hard time believing this Bluetooth device of yours would use anything else on the wire — then try this initializer instead (available since Swift 3):

```
init(
    sign: FloatingPointSign, 
    exponentBitPattern: UInt,
    significandBitPattern: UInt32
)
```

This is defined by the [`BinaryFloatingPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/binaryfloatingpoint/1849503-init) protocol:

> The values passed as `exponentBitPattern` and `significandBitPattern` are interpreted in the binary interchange format defined by the IEEE 754 specification.

The IEEE 754 mentioned above for (single precision) `Float` is:

- Sign bit: 1 bit
- Exponent width: 8 bits
- Significand precision: 24 bits (23 explicitly stored)

---

This other [`Float` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/float/1847937-init) should work fine as well:

```
init(bitPattern: UInt32)
```

In both cases, just watch out for *[big- vs little-endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating_point)* issues and you should be fine ;)

Comment: I think that [init(sign:exponent:significand:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint/1845755-init) will be easier to work with because it doesn't require IEEE, it requires only binary exponent. If everything fails, it's not too difficult to create the float using multiplication of `mantissa * exponent`.

Comment: I thought about using init(sign:exponent:significand:) the problem is that I don't have access to the IEEE 754 spec and have no idea of what it is the exponentBitPattern and significandBitPattern.
I've done some tests to see the bit pattern of a float
   ` let f: Float = 123.45
    var f_significandBitPattern = f.significandBitPattern  //7792230
    let b1 = String(f_significandBitPattern, radix: 2) // 
   11101101110011001100110
    var f_exponentBitPattern = f.exponentBitPattern // 133
   let b2 = String(f_exponentBitPattern, radix: 2) // 10000101`

Comment: @onthemoon The IEEE 754 format is detailed here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: @Paulo Mattos The biggest problem with the initializer you are proposing is that all of its parameters takes more than the 4 bytes that we have available as a "portable" format of the Float data. The significandBitPattern param alone takes all the 4 bytes available. In adition the UInt exponentBitPattern size is not defined, its architectural dependent so its not portable

Comment: @onthemoon The `init` signature is quite misleading. This is actually the good old IEEE 754 format: 1 sign bit, 8 bits exponent, 23 bits mantissa. This as portable as they come :-) Just watch out for little- vs big-ending issues and you should be fine!

Comment: @Paulo Mattos So,you are saying that, assuming the data received is encoded using the IEEE 754 format( 1 sign bit, 8 bits exponent, 23 bits mantissa), I will I be able to safely initialize the Float using init(
  sign: FloatingPointSign, 
  exponentBitPattern: UInt,
  significandBitPattern: UInt32
) ? That would be a solution for me. I just wonder what's the use for the other initializer : init(sign: FloatingPointSign, exponent: Int, significand: Float)

Comment: @onthemoon The other initializer just provides a general, IEEE independent, representation for power-of-2 floating point numbers (e.g., the mantissa is a float and not a bitpattern, etc).

Comment: I try to explain better the problem: in order to construct a Float with the initializer described by @Paulo Mattos, in which format do I need to have  the 4 Bytes of data that I'm receiving by BT? Because there are only 4 bytes available in the data packet and the initializer Paulo is talking about takes 8 Bytes for the FloatingPointSign param, another 8 Bytes for the exponentBitPattern param and 4 bytes for the significandBitPattern param. So the 2 things don't match

Comment: Just follow [this format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32), ignoring the upper bits. As Wikipedia clearly states, IEEE 754 single precision only takes **4 bytes**, which is exactly what you have in hand. Sure, the aforementioned `init` takes in more bits than necessary but they won't be used... you are reading too much into the declared types and ignoring what the IEEE standard says.

Comment: ...for instance, the **significand** takes exactly 23 bits but unfortunately Swift doesn't support a `UInt23` type. As such, what's the *closest* integer type that should be used instead? That would be `UInt32`, as used by the `init` above.

Comment: @ Paulo Mattos. Thanks for the clarification. So instead of using the above mentioned initializer wouldn't be easier to just use public init(bitPattern: UInt32). This way I just throw the 4 bytes received ( formatted according to the IEEE 754)  into this initializer without having to manually work out every single part. Am I right?

Comment: @onthemoon Yes, might work even better! Just watch out for big- vs little-endianness issues and you should be fine ;)