# How to extract SFLOAT value from Bluetooth LE data for 1822 PulseOximeter using CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, gatt

I'm working on an iOS app that is to read pulse oximeter data from a **Bluetooth LE** enabled device, using **CoreBluetooth** on **iOS 11.4** in **Swift 4.1**.

I've got the **CBCentralManager** searching for peripherals, I find the **CBPeripheral** I am interested in, I verify that it has the **0x1822** *Pulse Oximeter Service*, as described by Bluetooth SIG [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.pulse_oximeter.xml).  (You may need to register with Bluetooth SIG to access that link.  It's free but takes a day or two.)

After that, I connect to it, then I discover services:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
}
```

Then in my **peripheral:didDiscoverServices** I discover GATT characteristics:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?){
    for service in peripheral.services ?? [] {
        if service.uuid.uuidString == "1822" {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }
}
```

From that I see the the following characteristics (**CBCharacteristic.uuid**) available: 0x2A5F, 0x2A5E, 0x2a60, and 0x2A52.  I then subscribe to updates for **0x2A5F**, which is *PLX Continuous Measurement*, which is described [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.plx_continuous_measurement.xml):

```
if service.uuid.uuidString == "1822" && characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A5F" {
    // pulseox continuous
    print("[SUBSCRIBING TO UPDATES FOR SERVICE 1822 'PulseOx' for Characteristic 2A5F 'PLX Continuous']")
    peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)    
}
```

I then begin to receive back 20-byte packets in my **peripheral:didUpdateValueFor** method:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

    if characteristic.service.uuid.uuidString == "1822" && characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A5F" {
        if let data = characteristic.value {
            var values = [UInt8](repeating:0, count:data.count)
            data.copyBytes(to: &values, count: data.count)
        }
    }
}
```

From the reference doc you can see the first byte is a bunch of bitfields describing which optional values are included in the packet.  The next 2 bytes are an **SFLOAT** value for the *SpO2PR-Normal - SpO2* (oxygenation) reading, and the following 2 bytes are another **SFLOAT** value for the 
*SpO2PR-Normal - PR* (pulse rate) value.

Bluetooth SIG lists an **SFLOAT** as an **IEEE-11073 16-bit SFLOAT** [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/format-types).  IEEE's [document on IEEE-11073](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/11073-20601-2014.html) is not publicly listed, and is [available for purchase](https://www.techstreet.com/ieee/standards/ieee-p11073-20601?gateway_code=ieee&vendor_id=6084&product_id=1943018), but I'd prefer to avoid that.

Any idea how to decode?  I found another question on Stack Overflow referencing the normal [32-bit Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517629/how-to-parse-a-float-sent-by-a-bluetooth-device-in-swift), but that question was for a different type of Float, and its answer was not applicable.

Comment: Did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564270/how-to-convert-ieee-11073-16-bit-sfloat-to-simple-float-in-java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here it is:

**Xcode 9.4.1** or **Xcode 10.0 beta 3**

**iOS 11.4.1** or **iOS 12.0 beta 3**

**Swift 4.1.2** or **Swift 4.2**

```
func floatFromTwosComplementUInt16(_ value: UInt16, havingBitsInValueIncludingSign bitsInValueIncludingSign: Int) -> Float {
    // calculate a signed float from a two's complement signed value
    // represented in the lowest n ("bitsInValueIncludingSign") bits
    // of the UInt16 value
    let signMask: UInt16 = UInt16(0x1) << (bitsInValueIncludingSign - 1)
    let signMultiplier: Float = (value & signMask == 0) ? 1.0 : -1.0

    var valuePart = value
    if signMultiplier < 0 {
        // Undo two's complement if it's negative
        var valueMask = UInt16(1)
        for _ in 0 ..< bitsInValueIncludingSign - 2 {
            valueMask = valueMask << 1
            valueMask += 1
        }
        valuePart = ((~value) & valueMask) &+ 1
    }

    let floatValue = Float(valuePart) * signMultiplier

    return floatValue
}

func extractSFloat(values: [UInt8], startingIndex index: Int) -> Float {
    // IEEE-11073 16-bit SFLOAT -> Float
    let full = UInt16(values[index+1]) * 256 + UInt16(values[index])

    // Check special values defined by SFLOAT first
    if full == 0x07FF {
        return Float.nan
    } else if full == 0x800 {
        return Float.nan // This is really NRes, "Not at this Resolution"
    } else if full == 0x7FE {
        return Float.infinity
    } else if full == 0x0802 {
        return -Float.infinity // This is really negative infinity
    } else if full == 0x801 {
        return Float.nan // This is really RESERVED FOR FUTURE USE
    }

    // Get exponent (high 4 bits)
    let expo = (full & 0xF000) >> 12
    let expoFloat = floatFromTwosComplementUInt16(expo, havingBitsInValueIncludingSign: 4)

    // Get mantissa (low 12 bits)
    let mantissa = full & 0x0FFF
    let mantissaFloat = floatFromTwosComplementUInt16(mantissa, havingBitsInValueIncludingSign: 12)

    // Put it together
    let finalValue = mantissaFloat * pow(10.0, expoFloat)

    return finalValue
}
```

The **extraSFloat** method takes a Uint8 array and an index into that array to indicate where the SFLOAT is.  For example, if the array was two bytes (just the two bytes of the SFLOAT), then you would say:

```
let floatValue = extractSFloat(values: array, startingIndex: 0)
```

I did it this way because when working with Bluetooth data I always ended up with an array of **UInt8** values containing the data I needed to decode.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks so much.

Comment: I can validate that this parsing worked well with a Nonin Pulse Oximeter

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it in **Swift 5** (XCode 12.4)

```swift
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        guard characteristic.service.uuid == CBUUID(string: "1822"),
              characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: "2A5F"),
              let data = characteristic.value else {
            return
        }
        
        let numberOfBytes = data.count
        var byteArray = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: numberOfBytes)
        (data as NSData).getBytes(&byteArray, length: numberOfBytes)
        
        logger.debug("Data: \(byteArray)")
        
        let oxygenation = byteArray[1]
        let heartRate = byteArray[3]
    }
```

Taken from my tutorial ["Reverse Engineering Bluetooth Devices - An Introduction to CoreBluetooth"](https://itnext.io/reverse-engineering-bluetooth-devices-82d868edec0c)

Comment: The question asks how to decode the sfloat (i.e. medfloat16). This doesn't look like it does that. Did you mean this to be an answer?