# get values(pressure blood) from ble device in flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, uuid, device

I used this code and utilized the flutter_reactive_ble package to read the blood pressure (systolic, diastolic) from my device in mmHg and pulse rate in bpm, but I am struggling to figure out how to do it , In my console, I received :

D/BluetoothGatt(21288): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00002a35-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
I/flutter (21288): Received raw data for blood pressure measurement: [222, 136, 244, 32, 243, 255, 7, 228, 7, 1, 19, 22, 55, 0, 188, 242, 1, 68, 1]

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('BLE Scanner'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: _scanForDevices,
                        child: Text('Scan for Devices'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Text('Discovered Devices:'),
                    Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: devices.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                final device = devices[index];
                                return ListTile(
                                    title: Text(device.name ?? 'Unknown'),
                                    subtitle: Text(device.id),
                                    onTap: () {
                                        _connectToDevice(device.id);
                                        _subscribeToBloodPressureMeasurement(device.id);
                                    },
                                );
                            },
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        ),
    );
}

void _scanForDevices() {
    flutterReactiveBle.scanForDevices(
        withServices: [],
        scanMode: ScanMode.lowLatency,
    ).listen(
        (device) {
            final existingDeviceIndex =
                devices.indexWhere((d) => d.id == device.id);
            if (existingDeviceIndex != -1) {
                setState(() {
                    devices[existingDeviceIndex] = device;
                });
            } else {
                setState(() {
                    devices.add(device);
                });
            }
        },
        onError: (error) {
            print('Error: $error');
        },
    );
}

void _connectToDevice(String deviceId) {
    flutterReactiveBle
        .connectToDevice(
        id: deviceId,
        servicesWithCharacteristicsToDiscover: {
            Uuid.parse('00001810-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'): [                    // Caractéristique de mesure de la pression artérielle                    Uuid.parse('00002a35-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'),                    // Caractéristique des fonctionnalités de la pression artérielle                    Uuid.parse('00002a49-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'),                ],
        },
        connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    )
        .listen(
        (connectionState) {
            // Gérez les mises à jour de l'état de connexion
            if (connectionState == DeviceConnectionState.connected) {
                print("Connected successfully to device: $deviceId");
                _subscribeToBloodPressureMeasurement(deviceId);
            }
        },
        onError: (error) {
            print('Error connecting to device: $error');
            // Gérez les erreurs éventuelles
        },
    );
}

void _subscribeToBloodPressureMeasurement(String deviceId) {
    final bloodPressureCharacteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
        characteristicId: Uuid.parse('00002a35-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'),
        deviceId: deviceId,
        serviceId: Uuid.parse('00001810-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'),
    );

    // Souscrire à la caractéristique de mesure de la pression artérielle
    flutterReactiveBle
        .subscribeToCharacteristic(bloodPressureCharacteristic)
        .listen(
        (data) {
            print('Received raw data for blood pressure measurement: $data');
            // Traitez les données de notification ici
        },
        onError: (error) {
            print('Error subscribing to blood pressure measurement: $error');
            // Gérez les erreurs éventuelles lors de l'abonnement
        },
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the service: 0000**1810**-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. This is the 16-bit UUID template, so the actual number you care about is 0x1810.

Look that up in the [Assigned Numbers](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Files/Specification/HTML/Assigned_Numbers/out/en/Assigned_Numbers.pdf?v=1710701649390) doc, and find that this is the Blood Pressure Service.

Go the [Specifications](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/) page and pull up [the latest version](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/blood-pressure-service-1-1-1/).

Read this document. Seriously, people get so lost because they won't read the docs.

That said, this particular spec is terrible. Just terrible. It doesn't carefully explain the format, but it does tell you how the service works.

With that, we look up the characteristic UUID, 0x2a35, which is the Blood Pressure Measurement. Like I said, this service doc is terrible and doesn't explain it well, but it is documented well in [the YAML](https://bitbucket.org/bluetooth-SIG/public/src/main/gss/org.bluetooth.characteristic.blood_pressure_measurement.yaml).

So, with that in hand, let's decode.

### Flags (1 byte)

222 = b11011110 : Reading from LSB to MSB, this indicates:

- Pressure in mmHg
- Timestamp is included
- Pulse rate is included
- User ID is included
- Status is include
- And there are set bits in the reserved section (110, should be 000). That's strange. It may mean there's a non-obvious but documented extension this is using, or it may mean that this is something custom that the manufacturer is doing. You'd want to check their docs.

### Systolic mmHg (medfloat16, which is 2 bytes, little endian)

136, 244 -> 116

The format here, medfloat16, also called sfloat, is a 16-bit floating point. For an example of computing it, see [How to extract SFLOAT value from Bluetooth LE data for 1822 PulseOximeter using CoreBluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249335/how-to-extract-sfloat-value-from-bluetooth-le-data-for-1822-pulseoximeter-using).

### Diastolic mmHg (medfloat16)

32, 243 -> 80

### MAP (medfloat16)

255, 7 -> NaN (So this isn't actually available)

### Timestamp (7 byte [date_time](https://bitbucket.org/bluetooth-SIG/public/src/main/gss/org.bluetooth.characteristic.date_time.yaml) struct)

228, 7 -> 2020 (7<<8 + 228 because it's little endian)

1, 19, 22, 55, 0  -> Jan 19, 22:55:00

### User ID (1 byte)

1

### Status (2 bytes)

0001 0100 0100

- Irregular pulse
- The reserved bits that should be zero are 000101. Again, this may be a documented extension I'm not aware of, or a proprietary extension. You'd have to check the docs.

BTW, of some use is the [Blood Pressure Profile](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/blp-1-1-1/) specification, which is a collection of services, including the Blood Pressure Service, that most blood pressure reporting devices would include. It can be useful in order to know what else is likely to be available, and provides broader rules on how discovery works, etc. In practice, most people working on mobile apps can just skip to the service docs, but it's nice to know the profile docs exist.

Comment: Thank you for your response,Could you please tell me how you calculated that? How did you get 116 from 136, 244?

Comment: See the link in that section. "For an example of computing it, see..."